# Translating "Blood isn't always thicker than water."

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

My step grandpa passed, and I want a tattoo in latin that says, "Blood isn't always thicker than water." I would greatly appreciate it if someone translates this.

Answer (score 4):

The proverb "blood is thicker than water" originated in German, so all Latin versions are translations from that. The one I've seen most often is:

> Sangvis aqvā densior est.

*Densior* is quite literally "thicker". You could also use *spissior* "denser" or *dūrābilior* "harder to break"; either of those can be substituted in freely.

Another Latin proverb is "no man is always wise":

> Nemō mortālium omnibus hōrīs sapit.

(Literally, "nobody among the mortals is wise at every point in time".)

Combining the phrasing from those two would give:

> Sangvis nōn omnibus hōrīs qvam aqvā densior est.

I added the *qvam* to make it clear which ablative goes where, since there are two in a row. But you can freely drop the *qvam* and *est* without affecting the meaning.

Comment: It's a tattoo, it has to be more epigrammatic than that. _Sanguis non omnibus quam aqua densior_ ("for all people"), at most: I'd drop the "hours" too. Or, if we allow ourselves the (neo-Latin) diacritic for the ablative, _Sanguis aquâ non omnibus densior_.

Comment: Yes, more epigrammatic, from NickNicholas. But *iunctior* 'closer in friendship,'  might be better than *densior* 'more crowded.'